# Locate decimal even if everything after decimal is a zero

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to find the location of a decimal point, if it exists and even if everything after the decimal is a zero.

This type of question has appeared many times, but I have not seen anything that accounts for the actual formatting.

Scenario: An Excel spreadsheet was read into R. All numbers that have more than a specific number of decimal places need to be flagged. My vector has about 1,000 entries.

```
string = as.character(c(123, 0.123, 123.00000, 123.0, 123., 123.4567,  123.456789))
pattern = '\\.'
library(stringi)`
```

This is NOT what I want

```
str_locate(string = string, pattern = pattern)[1:length(string), 1]
#[1] NA  2 NA NA NA  4  4
```

I want

```
#[1] NA 2 4 4 4 4 4
```

If I change string to

```
string = c('123', '0.123', '123.00000', '123.0', '123.', '123.4567', '123.456789')
```

Then I get the correct answer with

```
str_locate(string = string, pattern = pattern)[1:length(string), 1]
#[1] NA  2  4  4  4  4  4
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the numbers into R as strings in the first place, using the `colClasses = "character"` option to `read.csv`. (See documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html#Variations-on-read_002etable) and [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html).) If you read them as numbers and then convert them to strings, 123.000 will convert to "123" and you will loose the information you are looking for.

**Explanation**

When you execute

```
string = as.character(c(123.000))
```

what happens is `123.000` is interpreted as a numeric literal and stored as the the number `123`. When you convert the number to a string with `as.character` you get `"123"`. You will see this if you print `string`. So of course you will not see the decimal point when you search the string because it has been lost in the conversions.